# using audio visualizer in android

Tags: android, visualizer

I'm trying to get the Waveform visualisation for an audio in my local device, and I'm trying to use the Visualizer package (`import android.media.audiofx.Visualizer`) , but, it continuously crashes giving me the following logs:

```
E/AudioEffect: set(): AudioFlinger could not create effect e46b26a0-dddd-11db-8afd-0002a5d5c51b / NULL, status: -1
E/visualizers-JNI: Visualizer initCheck failed -3
E/Visualizer-JAVA: Error code -3 when initializing Visualizer.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.musicit.player, PID: 7181
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:473)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7750)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7727)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:858)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29115)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8168)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1037)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:468)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7750) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7727) 
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:858) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29115) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8168) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1037) 
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -3
        at android.media.audiofx.Visualizer.<init>(Visualizer.java:238)
        at com.musicit.player.playerVisualizer.setAudioSessionId(playerVisualizer.kt:49)
        at com.musicit.player.MainActivity.playSong(MainActivity.kt:89)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:468) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7750) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7727) 
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:858) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29115) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8168) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1037)
```

The way I did it is very straightforward, just to see how it works:

I have this :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    fun onPlayClick(view: View) {
        var song = '/path/that/definitelyexists.mp3';
        playMusic(song);
    }

    fun playMusic(song: String){
    val mediaPlayerInstance = MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayerInstance.setAudioAttributes(
        AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .build()
    );
    mediaPlayerInstance.setDataSource(audioPath);
    mediaPlayerInstance.prepare();
    mediaPlayerInstance.start();

    

    val visualiz = findViewById<MVisualizer>(R.id.musicitviz);
    visualiz.setAudioSessionId(mediaPlayerInstance.audioSessionId);
   }
}
```

```
<com.musicit.music.Visualizer
    android:id="@+id/musicitviz"
    android:layout_width="267dp"
    android:layout_height="258dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

```
class Visualizer(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : View(context, attrs) {
    private var paint = Paint();
    private var visualizer: Visualizer? = null;
    private var waveformByteArray: ByteArray? = null;

    init {
        paint.color = Color.rgb(244, 40, 30);
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        waveformByteArray?.let { waveformByteArray ->
            if(waveformByteArray.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d(": ", "waveformbytearray is null.");
                return;
            }else{
                Log.d(": ", "waveformbytearray is not null.");
            }
        }


    }

    fun setAudioSessionId(audioSessionId: Int) {
        if(visualizer != null){
            visualizer?.release();
        }

        val newVisualizer = Visualizer(audioSessionId);
        newVisualizer.enabled = true;
        newVisualizer.captureSize = Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1];
        newVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(object: Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener {
            override fun onWaveFormDataCapture(
                visualizer: Visualizer?,
                waveform: ByteArray?,
                samplingRate: Int
            ) {
                waveformByteArray = waveform;
                Log.d("TAG: ", "I am updating the waveform")
                invalidate();
            }

            override fun onFftDataCapture(
                visualizer: Visualizer?,
                fft: ByteArray?,
                samplingRate: Int
            ) {
            }
        }, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, false);
        newVisualizer.enabled = true;
        visualizer = newVisualizer;
    }
}
```

I've tried adding permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>`

restarting my device, and also updating the api level to >=29:

```
android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.musicit.music"
        minSdk 29
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    namespace 'com.musicit.music'
}
```

as suggested in posts with similar problem but, nothing really works, wonder how I can solve the problem.

EDIT: I also tried setting on prepare listener, but to no avail, the error message is still the same, with Error code -3:

```
val mediaPlayerInstance = MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayerInstance.setAudioAttributes(
        AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .build()
    );
    mediaPlayerInstance.setDataSource(audioPath);


 mediaPlayerInstance.setOnPreparedListener(object: MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
            override fun onPrepared(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
                if(mp == null) {
                    return;
                }


                val visualiz = findViewById<Visualizer>(R.id.musicitviz);
                visualiz.setAudioSessionId(mp.audioSessionId);
                visualiz.enableVisualization();
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        mediaPlayerInstance.prepare();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad I can tell you I solved the issue. I tried to run your code and got the same error. I found the solution [here](https://github.com/GautamChibde/android-audio-visualizer/issues/9). They say you need to have permission **RECORD_AUDIO**. After requesting this permission the error was gone! You have to declare this is in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

And then request permission like this:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO), 123 /* your request code */)
```

That's all. When [OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback) is called you can create the `android.media.audiofx.Visualizer`. But not before.

I also told you to use `setOnPreparedListener`. That wasn't completely correct. If you only play local files you can stick to `prepare` and please remove the `setOnPreparedListener`. But if you want to play URLs from web servers for example please switch to `prepareAsync` and `setOnPreparedListener`. It's explained in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#prepare()):

> For files, it is OK to call prepare(), which blocks until MediaPlayer
> is ready for playback.